# Visual Studio Code Remote Development crashing AWS instance

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-ec2, ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I came across Visual Studio Remote Development crashing a AWS instance and i'm hoping to solve this by increasing the instance memory. I have not tested it out yet.

Connection is ok and I can do Remote Development with no problems but only for a few seconds.

I am using Visual Studio Code **Remote - SSH 0.51.0**

Anyone experiencing this?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is a current issue.  The size of the EC2 instance does not matter.  At this very moment, vscode 1.46.1 just took down one of my m5.xlarge as I typed this comment.  You don't need to interact, vscode will crash/hang your instance with out any effort on your part.  This comment comes on the heals of many attempts/configs/adjustments/distros (cento/ubuntu) and also waiting for the next stable/nightly builds, only to observe the same effect in all cases.  This is a very large issue, for now work needs to continue with the old tried and true ssh tools, I hope MS can jump in here and fix it up or show us our mistake.

- Ubuntu 20.04
- VScode 1.46.1
- Remote SSH v0.51.0
- OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: I have just replicated this event between my machine and a tablet in my network.  Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on the tablet, 5 mins into a vcsode Remote SSH session and poof the tablet goes offline from the SSH session and the tablet is not responsive to direct touch/keyboard/mouse input or screen refresh, totally hung.  So I have confirmed for myself that this issue is not an AWS issue.  I hope the tablet logs will have something more to point towards a solution.

Comment: Irony is, having such a big issue it's still not been taken much seriously by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when working with my Typescipt project on EC2.
Here is an answer that solved the issue for me:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2692#issuecomment-852548425

If you are working on a typescript repo, I suggest trying the same:

Quoting the original answser:

> I had the very same problem with VSCode connecting to my EC2 instance.
> However, this wasn't the first time that I had VSCode running with an
> EC2, and the other server that I had, was running smoothly. What was
> the difference between my old server (that is actually still running)
> and the new one? That in the old one, I was running an Apache server
> with only PHP code, so basically, I was only using VSCode for setting
> files and PHP.
>
> I created a new server, started writing PHP again and everything was
> going fine. The problem came when I started writing JS code in a
> Node.js, and suddenly became very slow and began crashing, just with
> the same symptoms described above.
>
> So, it looks like VSCode has an extension built-in in a release called
> "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" but you can find it
> easily by looking at the extensions box and writing: "@Builtin
> typescript". Find it and disable it and you'll be just fine.

[image]

However, it has downsides - mainly the coding experience would suck after you disabled the tool.

So Here is another way that is worth a shot:

According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2692#issuecomment-901643826, VS Code Insider solved the issue.

So, try to download and use VS Code Insider: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

UPDATE:

Nah, VS Code Insider did not work for me.
Disabling "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" definitely worked, at the cost of shitty coding experience.